# Problems with python versions and environemnts on os x El Capitan

Tags: python, macos

I'm learning python and I'm using OS X. I've installed anaconda 3 and set up env called testenv with python 3.5. Then I activated recently created env and installed several packages such as numpy, pandas and opencv3. Nevertheless, when I run python shell and type "import numpy" I get the following errors:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyBuffer_Type
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
```

The same happens with other packages.

Answer (score 1):

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/**init**.py", line
>   180, in

Python is picking up the packages from the system's Python packages and not from the packages installed in your virtualenv i.e. `testenv`.

Be sure that you have activated the virtualenv with something like:

```
source testenv/bin/activate
```

and then try running Python.

And you said you set it up with `Python 3.5` but it's picking path with `python2.7`.
Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: I've activated the virtualenv, so the problem in something else.

Comment: Is it still giving the path to the /usr/local/lib/python2.7 in the error?
Check if you are using the right one! or better try creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by simply writing this command:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade numpy
```

Another possible method to fix it is to eliminate `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` in PYTHONPATH

Comment: It uses the correct version python3 to upgrade numpy to an appropriate version.

Comment: NO No No..... If you are using a virtualenv (and you should be) there is absolutely no need for sudo. What you just did was upgrade python3 at a System level (i.e. for everyone) - the sudo created a new shell, this will loose your virtualenv setting.. You soon will need to reformat and reinstall your machine if you keep doing sudo commands.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac.... this is how to do this safely

```
brew install python3
```

Lets now add a virtual env called *pe35*

```
python3 -m venv ~/pe35
```

Now lets use the virtualenv

```
 source ~/pe35/bin/activate
```

If you want a symbol - place this in you .bash_profile

```
 alias pe35='source ~/pe35/bin/activate'
```

Now to install numpy in your virtualenv

```
pip install numpy
```